# SQL statement select column from same table in one query with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 2 tables; the first table has good and seller ID which this ID found in the second table.

`goodsinfo`:

| seller ID | goods ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 7 |

Second Table `mainrefer`:

| ID | Codename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Richard |
| 3 | Sam |
| 5 | Mobile phones |
| 7 | IT cables |

I want to get a result like this:

| Seller name | goods name |
| --- | --- |
| Richard | Mobile phones |
| Sam | IT Cables |

I tried many queries with my self but cannot reach how to get diff value from 1 column at 1 query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the same table twice with different alias names

```
select seller.Codename as sellerName,
       goods.Codename as goodsName           
from goodsinfo g
join mainrefer seller on g.sellerID = seller.ID
join mainrefer goods on g.goodsID = goods.ID
```

Comment: thx @juergen d , thats works fine i just need to understand what is 'g' meaning

Comment: `g` is an alias name for the table `goodsinfo`. You can use it to make your SQL statements shorter when you don't want to use the full table name everywhere. But for the `mainrefer` table you need the alias to make a difference between the two joins. You could write the statement like this if you like: `select seller.Codename as sellerName, goods.Codename as goodsName from goodsinfo join mainrefer seller on goodsinfo.sellerID = seller.ID join mainrefer goods on goodsinfo.goodsID = goods.ID`